# How to fill a new list while iterating over another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

**Code**

```
#Variables
var1 = ['Warehouse Pencil 1.docx', 'Production Pen 20.docx']

list1 = []
for x in var1:
    splitted = x.split()
    a = [splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1]]
    list1.append(a)
    print(list1)
```

**Output**

```
[['Warehouse Pencil']]
[['Warehouse Pencil'], ['Production Pen']]
```

**Goal**

I am intending to split the list, grab the 1st and 2nd words for each section, and put them into a new list.

**Question**

Why is my output giving me a weird output? Where am I going wrong?

**Desired Output**

My desired output should look like this:

```
['Warehouse Pencil', 'Production Pen']
```

Grabbing the 1st and 2nd words and put them into 1 list.

Comment: Just remove the brackets around `a = splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should fix it - move the print statement out of the loop, and make `a` a string rather than a list.

```
#Variables
var1 = ['Warehouse Pencil 1.docx', 'Production Pen 20.docx']

list1 = []
for x in var1:
    splitted = x.split()
    a = splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1]
    list1.append(a)
print(list1)
```

**Output:**

```
['Warehouse Pencil', 'Production Pen']
```

**You could also use a list comprehension:**

```
>>> [' '.join(x.split()[:2]) for x in var1]
['Warehouse Pencil', 'Production Pen']
```

Comment: Thank you, I see you removed the `[]` and also moved indentation for the print. How did the indentation matter in this scenario? Just curious

Comment: thanks for the explanation! and also what is happening at list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the method [`str.rfind(sub)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind). It returns the highest index in the string where substring `sub` (space in your case) is found:

```
[i[:i.rfind(' ')] for i in var1]
# ['Warehouse Pencil', 'Production Pen']
```

Alternatively, you can use the method [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit). It splits the string starting from the right:

```
[i.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0] for i in var1]
# ['Warehouse Pencil', 'Production Pen']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the filename.
We can use the following approach.

```
import pathlib

var1 = ['Warehouse Pencil 1.docx', 'Production Pen 20.docx']
file_name = []

for i in var1:
    p = pathlib.Path(i)
    file_name.append(p.stem)
    
print(file_name)
```

```
['Warehouse Pencil 1', 'Production Pen 20']

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [list.extend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Since this keyword hasn't been mentioned in the other answers, you can just extend your list instead of appending it.

```py
var1 = ['Warehouse Pencil 1.docx', 'Production Pen 20.docx']

list1 = []
for x in var1:
    splitted = x.split()
    a = [splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1]]
    list1.extend(a)  # Notice the difference here! 
print(list1)
```